# Disable Context Menu - Flash Professional Export (Flash 11.2 - CS6)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, right-click

Flash 11.2 added the capability to attach an right-click mouse-event to MovieClips.
EX:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN, myFunction);
```

When this listener is attached, it should be impossible for the Context Menu to pop up on right-click of this object.  Flash disables the functionality.

When I export a new SWF from Flash Professional (CS6 Mac) and that SWF is embedded in the browser, it works as expected.  Right-click does not spawn a context menu.

However, this is not the case with the flash player within Flash Professional.  The flash player presented within Flash Professional just after export does not hide the context menu.
[image: Incorrect Behavior]

While it's possible for me to develop by simply exporting the SWF and testing it in-browser, I lose out on all the debugging that Flash Professional offers.

How do I fix this issue?

## Update 1

This issue isn't with exporting to 11.2 - I can already do that.  All changes mentioned in [this tutorial](https://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html) have already been made with base install of Flash Professional CS6.

running:

```
trace(flash.system.Capabilities.version)
```

results in:

> MAC 11,2,202,228

Comment: Report it to Adobe as a bug.
please Report it to Adobe as a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I would have thought 11.2 would be included but anyway you can add a new Flash Player version within Flash Professional.

Here are some instructions for doing so (scroll down to manual install):

https://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html

The instructions are for CS5 or CS5.5 but presumably will be roughly the same for CS6. Make sure to change things that need changing - e.g. the playerglobal should be https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/playerglobal11_2.swc as opposed to the 11.0 one that they link to.

Comment: This issue isn't with exporting to 11.2 - I can already do that.  All changes mentioned in the tutorial have already been made with base install of Flash Professional CS6.

See updates in question.

Comment: @JonSandness I see. Not sure if this will help, but try adding a right click listener to the stage itself and see if that prevents it from popping up.